# can't understand showbit() function in bitwise operatrers in C

Tags: c, binary, decimal, bitwise-operators, and-operator

```
/* Print binary equivalent of characters using showbits( ) function */

#include <stdio.h>

void showbits(unsigned char);
    
int main() {
    unsigned char num;
    
    for (num = 0; num <= 5; num++) {
        printf("\nDecimal %d is same as binary ", num);
        showbits(num);
    }

    return 0;
}

void showbits(unsigned char n) {
    int i;
    unsigned char j, k, andmask;
    
    for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        j = i;
        andmask = 1 << j;
        k = n & andmask;
        k == 0 ? printf("0") : printf("1");
    }
}
```

Sample numbers assigned for `num` : 0,1,2,3,4 ...

Can someone explain in detail what is going on in
`k = n & andmask`?  How can `n`, which is a number such as 2, be an operand of the same `&` operator with `andmask`, eg 10000000,  since 2 is a 1-digit value and 10000000 is a multiple-digit value?

Also why is `char` is used for `n` and not `int`?

Comment: Ask the author of the function.

Comment: `2 is 1 digit value` in decimal. It's (at least) a 2-digit value in binary `10`, but you can always add more `0`s in front of it without changing its numeric value, like `000010` in binary is still 2 in decimal

Comment: The size of `char` is 1 byte. `int` is more than 1 byte. 
If you're only using the numbers from 0 to 5, then 1 byte is enough.

Comment: In `n & 10000000 (binary)`, the leftmost bit in `n` determines the outcome, because all other bits in the output must become 0. If the leftmost bit is 0, then the outcome (k) is `00000000 (binary)` which is just 0. Then one can print "0" based on this condition; on the other hand, if the leftmost bit is 1, then `k` is nonzero so print "1". Then, to tell whether the second bit is 0, you use `n & 01000000 (binary)`. Then change the mask to `00100000 (binary)`, `00010000 (binary)`, `00001000 (binary)` and so on and whether k is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's walk through it.

Assume `n` is `2`.  The *binary representation* of `2` is `00000010`.

The first time through the loop `j` is equal to `7`.  The statement

```
andmask = 1 << j;
```

takes the binary representation of `1`, which is `00000001`, and shifts it left seven places, giving us `10000000`, assigning to `andmask`.

The statement

```
k = n & andmask;
```

performs a *bitwise AND* operation on `n` and `andmask`:

```
  00000010
& 10000000
  --------
  00000000
```

and assigns the result to `k`.  Then if `k` is `0` it prints a "0", otherwise it prints a "1".

So, each time through the loop, it's basically doing

```
j   andmask          n     result    output
-  --------   --------   --------    ------
7  10000000 & 00000010   00000000       "0"
6  01000000 & 00000010   00000000       "0"
5  00100000 & 00000010   00000000       "0"
4  00010000 & 00000010   00000000       "0"
3  00001000 & 00000010   00000000       "0"
2  00000100 & 00000010   00000000       "0"
1  00000010 & 00000010   00000010       "1"    
0  00000001 & 00000010   00000000       "0"
```

Thus, the output is "00000010".

So the `showbits` function is printing out the binary representation of its input value.  They're using `unsigned char` instead of `int` to keep the output easy to read (8 bits instead of 16 or 32).

Some issues with this code:

- It assumes `unsigned char` is always 8 bits wide; while this is *usually* the case, it can be (and historically has been) wider than this.  To be safe, it should be using the `CHAR_BIT` macro defined in `limits.h`:

  ```
  #include <limits.h>
  ...
  for ( i = CHAR_BIT - 1; i >= 0; i++ )
  {
    ...
  }
  ```

  `?:` is not a *control structure* and should not be used to replace an `if-else` - that would be more properly written as

  ```
  printf( "%c", k ? '1' : '0' );
  ```

  That tells `printf` to output a `'1'` if `k` is non-zero, `'0'` otherwise.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explaination.Just another silly question : so 2 will automatically convert to 00000010 ,then what is the point of using showbit() ,can't i just print this binary of 2 directly to screen without showbit()?

Comment: @NitinBhartiya printf does not automatically work with that kind of representation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format

Comment: @NitinBhartiya-  Because C doesn't have a `printf` conversion specifier for binary output.  It has conversion specifiers for hexadecimal and octal output, but not binary.  We usually don't display binary because it's hard to read - `1fb6` and `017666` are easier to read than `0001111110110110`.

Comment: And `2` doesn't "convert to" `00000010` - it is internally represented as `00000010`.  All  values are internally represented as binary.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone explain in detail what is going on in `k = n & andmask`? How can n, which is a number such as 2, be an operand of the same `&` operator with `andmask`, eg 10000000, since 2 is 1 digit value and 10000000 is multiple digit value?

The number of digits in a number is a characteristic of a particular *representation* of that number.  In context of the code presented, you actually appear to be using two different forms of representation yourself:

- "2" seems to be expressed (i) in base 10, and (ii) without leading zeroes.

On the other hand, I take

- "10000000" as expressed (i) in base 2, and (ii) without leading zeroes.

In this combination of representations, your claim about the numbers of digits is true, but not particularly interesting.  Suppose we consider comparable representations.  For example, what if we express both numbers in base 256?  Both numbers have single-digit representations in that base.

Both numbers also have arbitrary-length multi-digit representations in base 256, formed by prepending any number of leading zeroes to the single-digit representations.  And of course, the same is true in any base.  Representations with leading zeroes are uncommon in human communication, but they are routine in computers because computers work most naturally with fixed-width numeric representations.

What matters for bitwise and (`&`) are base-2 representations of the operands, the width of one of C's built-in arithmetic types.  According to the rules of C, the operands of any arithmetic operators are converted, if necessary, to a common numeric type.  These have the same number of binary digits (*i.e.* bits) as each other, **some of which often being leading zeroes**.  As I infer you understand, the `&` operator computes a result by combining corresponding bits from those base-2 representations to determine the bits of the result.

That is, the bits combined are

```
(leading zeroes)10000000 & (leading zeroes)00000010
```

> Also why is `char` is used for `n` and not `int`?

It is `unsigned char`, not `char`, and it is used for both `n` and `andmask`.  That is a developer choice.  `n` could be made an `int` instead, and the `showbits()` function would produce the same output for all inputs representable in the original data type (`unsigned char`).

Comment: Thank you for putting this much effort in my question.one more question : since 2 will automatically convert to binary from decimal before engaging with & operator, is there a way i can skip showbit() function and just print the binary form through a format specifier ?

Comment: @NitinBhartiya, as I wrote in another comment, no, you cannot.  At least, not in standard C.  More precisely, the specifications for `printf` do not define a format specifier for outputting binary representation directly.  Your choices there are octal, decimal, and hexadecimal.

Answer (score -1):

At first glance this function seems to print an 8-bit value in binary representation (0s and 1s). It creates a mask that isolate each bit of the char value (setting all other bits to 0) and prints "0" if the masked value is 0 or "1" otherwise. `char` is used here because the function is designed to print the binary representation of an 8-bit value. If `int` was used here, only values in the range [0-255] would correctly be printed.
I don't understand your point with the 1-digit value and multiple-digit value.

Comment: i mean to do a truth comparison you need  2 values like 1 & 1 will be 1 ,1 & 0 will be 0 but here u have  2 & 10000000 .how can you compare 2 with 10000000 for an output?

Comment: @NitinBhartiya "2" is not even a valid binary digit.  It is `00000010` in binary (8-bit).

Comment: so 2 will automatically convert to 00000010 ,then what is the point of using showbit() ,can't i just print this binary of 2 directly to screen without showbit()?

Comment: @NitinBhartiya, I/O always involves converting between internal and external representations.  Occasionally these are the same, but often they are different.  You need `showbit()` because C does not define a built-in way to produce a binary external representation.  If you wanted to convert to octal or hexadecimal, however, then you could do it entirely with `scanf` and `printf`.